# Is updating gamma conjugate distributions always increasing?

Tags: bayesian, gamma-distribution, conjugate-prior

In Bayesian inference, the gamma distribution is the conjugate prior to many likelihood distributions: Poisson, exponential, normal (with known mean), etc.

The update rule seems to always *add* to $\alpha$ and $\beta$. For example, if:
$$
X \sim \Gamma(\alpha, \beta)\\
Y\sim Poisson(X)
$$
then
$$
X|Y \sim \Gamma(\alpha + Y, \beta + 1)
$$
Many examples can be found, e.g. here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior

Is it always true that the updated Gamma parameters are always larger? Could this be proven?

Formally, if $X \sim \Gamma(\alpha, \beta), X|Y \sim Gamma(\alpha', \beta'$), is it always true that $\alpha' \ge \alpha$ and $\beta' \ge \beta$?

Comment: You will find something similar with Beta conjugate distributions.  In both cases the parameters are in a sense measures of the information implicit in the distribution and increase with with more observations.  But this does not tell you about direction of change  the means of the distributions as you update with new observations

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a useful reference?